# texture sky doesnt work in blender 2.8 (Eevee render)

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, world

when i want make sky and sun i just use sky texture but with new render everything convert white, like this.
[image]

so can i fix it? or can i do another way to make sky and sun(with new render)
and sorry if i not speak English very well.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked and it is not supported in EEVEE (yet?) according to the official documentation. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/materials/nodes_support.html